# Analysis Projects: Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'OLE DB or ODBC error: We cannot convert the value null to type Logical

Tags: c#

we are using analysis service projects to create model and deploy it on azure analysis service. when ever i try to import a new table from data source then i got the following error :

Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'OLE DB or ODBC error: [Expression.Error] We cannot convert the value null to type Logical..

'.
Steps to create the above error:

1. Create an analysis service tabular project.
2. Select "integrated workspace" as analysis service instance.
3. Choose "SQL server 2017/Azure analysis services(1400) as compatibility level.
4. Go to "Project" -> properties and assign "asazure://westeurope.asazure.windows.net/projName:rw " in server and also provide "database" and "model" name.
5. select "import from datasource" and select "Azure Data Lake Store" , provide url of data lake store and  finally select a table to import.
6. click on the "import" button, the following error displayed:

Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'OLE DB or ODBC error: [Expression.Error] We cannot convert the value null to type Logical..

Note: 1. For testing we have taken a table containing one row and there is no null value in it.

If any one is currently using Analysis service project for model deployment, then please share your experience.

Answer (score 0):

In step 6, enter a numeric value in property "Page size in bytes (optional)" . Although this property is optional it requires some value.there's no documentation available on internet explaining it.